# Assign a print statement to a variable in a function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, function, variables, printing, variable-assignment

I'm trying to assign a print statement to a variable in a function:

```
def namer(fn, ln='Smith'):
    # return value, default value
    r = print "Your name is ", fn, ln
    return r
```

But when I run the module, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import m8
  File "m8.py", line 3
    r = print "Your name is ", fn, ln
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any explanation?

Comment: In Python 2.7, `print` is a statement. You cannot assign that to a variable. In Python 3.x, `print` is a function which needs to be invoked with parenthesis.

Comment: What would you expect a `print` to return, anyway? In 3.x (where it's a function) it will return `None`, so there's not much point in assigning it.

Comment: What are you doing here? Why not just return `"Your name is " + fn + ' ' + ln`?

Comment: You should go through the Python documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, in Python2.x, `print` is a statement. A statement is not an object, you cannot assign it to anything, you can just execute it.

Why would you want to return the `print` statement? Why not the string to be printed or a function that, when called would execute the print statement?

Answer (score 0):

The print statement only prints the value to your monitor. It doesn't make any sense to assign it to a variable.

If your code is meant to store the string in the variable r, then:

r = "Your name is " + fn + " "+ ln

This would work provided fn is a string, if not:

r= "Your name is " + str(fn) +" "+ ln

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't make sense to assign a print statement it makes sense to assign a print function to variable.

In this case you need to use the following import (only if using python 2)

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

A possible use case

```
import logging

use_print = True
if use_print:
    log_fun = print
else:
    log_fun = logging.info

log_fun('Spam')
```

The following statement will also be syntactically correct but it won't make sense

```
r = print('Something')
```

You will end up printing "Something" and assign `None` to `r` which is the return value of print function